# Image onClick open in new Tab in React

Tags: reactjs, image, onclick

I want my images from a React component to open in a new Tab on click.
One of the main problems is that I don't know how to pass image src to the function (src is passed through prop "picture")

`            src={require(picture)}

I found this solution, but can't really get it to work

```
    const openInNewTab = (url) => {
        const newWindow = window.open(url, '_blank', 'noopener,noreferrer')
        if (newWindow) newWindow.opener = null
    }
```

and on the image

`onClick={() => { openInNewTab(url) }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overcomplicating this, instead of creating a function, just wrap the `img` within an `a` tag with the image's `src` attribute as the `href` attribute. And make it open in a new window by setting the attribute `target` to `_blank`. Example:

```
<a href="https://picsum.photos/200/300" target="_blank">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" width="200" height="300"/>
</a>
```

By doing this you also improve the accesssibility of your application.

Comment: the solution is great, but I need to pass a lot of pictures from a local storage, so I'm using props and pathes instead of `url`, so how to pass it to `href`?

Comment: Just pass the src of the image to the href attribute: `href={your-img-src}`